# Card won't publish/Glassware stops

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to make my first Google Glass app (second if you count the Hello World project :) ), and need a little help. I created the first part, which turned out okay (the app shows up in both the voice command list and "launcher" and I can run it/speak to it) so I am pretty excited that I got this far! My question is, how do I get the card published to the timeline?:

```
package com.test.glass.glassnotes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.android.glass.app.Card;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get voice input results
    ArrayList<String> voiceResults = getIntent().getExtras()
            .getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    String voiceString = "";
    for(String str:voiceResults){
        voiceString = voiceString + " " + str;
    }
    voiceString = voiceString.trim();

            //Create card
            Card card1 = new Card(this);
            card1.setText(voiceString);
            card1.setFootnote("GlassNotes");
            View card1View = card1.toView();

            // Display card
            setContentView(card1View);
    }
}
```

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to Java, so I'm learning as I go along...

Also, it might be worth noting that the app I am trying to create is a simple notepad app, where the user would speak text and a new card would be added to the timeline for future reference, containing the spoken text. I am doing this in Eclipse/ADT with the GDK Sneak Peek.

Thanks in advance for any and all of your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a card published to the timeline, you need to use the GDK TimelineManager API documented at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/timeline/TimelineManager

For example:

```
mTimelineManager = TimelineManager.from(this);
mTimelineManager.insert(card);
```

Be aware that the cards on the timeline created using Card (the static cards) remain there only for 7 days (https://developers.google.com/glass/design/ui/static-cards).